# When multiple people try to save a transaction the user id is going null to the database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

When multiple people try to save a transaction the user id is going null to the database. I am fetching user information based on session id from database each time.
I have tried query string and session also.

below mentioned is the code to retrieve logged user information from database on session id and system name.

I used to call these constructor is web method

```
public clsLoggedUser()
    {
        try
        {
            string strUserId = "";
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["x"] == null)
            {
              
                string strSessionID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
                string strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Authority;
                string strSystemName = Convert.ToString(System.Net.Dns.Resolve(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName);

                OracleParameter[] objParam = new OracleParameter[3];
                objParam[0] = new OracleParameter("SESSIONID", OracleType.VarChar);
                objParam[1] = new OracleParameter("SYSNAME", OracleType.VarChar);
                objParam[2] = new OracleParameter("URL", OracleType.VarChar);

                objParam[0].Value = strSessionID.Trim();
                objParam[1].Value = strSystemName.Trim();
                objParam[2].Value = strUrl.Trim();

                DataTable dtUserDetails = clsOracleAccess.StaticExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "PACKCOMMON.GETLOGGEDUSERID", objParam, true).Tables[0];
                if (dtUserDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    strUserId = dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["APPLOCKID_NR"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Exception ex = new NullReferenceException();
                    clsErrorLogEntity.fn_AddNewErrorLog(DateTime.Now, "clsLoggedUser.cs (clsLoggedUser(-1)) [" + ex.Source + "]:" + ((String[])ex.StackTrace.Split(':'))[((String[])ex.StackTrace.Split(':')).Length - 1] + "", ex.Message, ex);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                strUserId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["x"].ToString().Trim();
            }
            
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserId))
            {
                OracleParameter[] objParam = new OracleParameter[1];
                objParam[0] = new OracleParameter("USERID", OracleType.Number);
                objParam[0].Value = Int32.Parse(strUserId);
                DataTable dtUserDetails = clsOracleAccess.StaticExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "HMPACK.GETUSERINFOBYID", objParam, true).Tables[0];
                if (dtUserDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["APPID_NR"].ToString());
                    UserName = dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["APPUNAME_CD"].ToString();
                    Password = dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["APPUACCESS_CD"].ToString();
                    UserCode = dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["APPCODE_CD"].ToString();
                    IsAdmin = Convert.ToChar(dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["ADMINUSER_YN"].ToString());
                    UserConID = Convert.ToInt32(dtUserDetails.Rows[0]["CONID_NR"].ToString());
                    IsLoggedIn = true;
                    blIsAdmin = IsAdmin == 'Y' ? true : false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
clsLoggedUser objclsLoggedUser = new clsLoggedUser();
objclsLoggedUser.UserName;
objclsLoggedUser.UserID;
```

Comment: I can't quite tell what you mean but did just want to point out that you probably don't have to use eg `ConvertToInt32(somerow["SOMECOL"].ToString())` - if your thing coming out of the database is an int, char etc you can just cast it rather than converting it to a string and then back to a number

Comment: As to your question; are you saying that when only one person uses it all is fine but when multiple people use it simultaneously, it seems to lose track of some user of variable and set it null?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, When multiple user do same transaction it collapse

Comment: On which line of code do you pause in the debugger and inspect to find it null? And which variable is null when it should not be?

Comment: @CaiusJard objclsLoggedUser.UserName; this the line I find null.

Comment: `objclsLoggedUser.UserName;` is not valid C#; it neither assigns the value nor makes use of it and it appears in a namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry can't comment yet)
I notice that there are quite a few possibilities to run trough that code and end up with a "objclsLoggedUser.UserName == null". If an exception occurs you might log using 'clsErrorLogEntity.fn_AddNewErrorLog' but 'if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserId))' has no else with a error logging. Your 'catch (Exception ex)' also doesn't log anything.
If you set a break point at those locations and run the code, you are likely to find the culprit. Or after the 'catch (Exception ex)' set:

```
catch (Exception ex)
if(UserName == null)
   throw new IllegalStateException($"User is NULL, HELP!! Some info: {HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID}");
```

Set a breakpoint on the throw or watch the errors to get a clue what is going wrong.

Comment: If you don't have the rep to comment, avoid posting answers that should be comments - they attract  downvotes which actively detract from your mission to get 50 rep to comment